# Blurred Side Bar in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

it is possible to create this effect in react native, for the side menu, ie if it is possible that when the menu is displayed, the content behind it and only the one that covers is blurry
[Sample Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUEdX.png)

Comment: [react-native-blur](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur)